# When $\|x\|_2$ becomes very close to $\|x\|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds

We [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalence)

$$\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt{d} \|x\|_2$$ for $x = (x_1, x_2,\dots, x_d)$. If we also  have $x_i \geq 0$, is any way to know how tight this inequality can be? In other words, are there specific conditions (e.g., sparsity, high dimensionality) to get $\|x\|_2 - \|x\|_1 \leq \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a very small positive number?

Comment: The more sparse $x$ is, the better your bound will be. In particular, if $x$ has at most $k$ non-zero entries, then 
$$
\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt{k}\|x\|_2,
$$
which leads to the bound
$$
\|x\|_2 - \|x\|_1 \leq (\sqrt{k} - 1) \|x\|_1.
$$
However, this approach does not lead to a "very small" (i.e. arbitrarily small) bound $\epsilon$ unless we have $k = 1$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "conditionality"?

Comment: You might find it useful to compare the ratio $\frac{\|x\|_2 - \|x\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$ to the ratio between the largest two entries of $x$. If this ratio is $1$ (i.e. the largest entry is repeated), then the best possible upper bound for $\frac{\|x\|_2 - \|x\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$ is $(\sqrt{2} - 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My mistake I meant dimensionality. How do we lead to $$\|x\|_2 - \|x\|_1 \leq (\sqrt{k} - 1) \|x\|_1$$ The $\sqrt{k}$ is with $||x||_2$ in
$$\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt{k}\|x\|_2$$ Can you please elaborate?

Comment: That should have been $\|x\|_1 - \|x\|_2$ instead, but otherwise the result is correct. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\|x\|_1 - \|x\|_2 &\leq \sqrt{k}\|x\|_2 - \|x\|_2
 = (\sqrt{k} - 1) \|x\|_2
\\&\leq (\sqrt{k} - 1)\|x\|_1
\end{align}
$$